# How to check the scroll bar status is already at top or at end?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrollbar

The scroll bar is shown when user set "overflow:auto;" and the user can scroll things from top to bottom. The problem is , how can the javascript/jquery check when the scroll bar is either at the bottom or at the top? So that

```
if (is_scrollbar_top || is_scrollbar_end)
//do some thing..
```

So are there any funciton/ way to check such status? Thanks

Updated: Not working- using jquery ui dialog

**html:**

```
<div class = "dialog" id="dialog" title="Past Issues"></div>
```

**javascript:**

```
$('#pastIssues').click(function (event) {
            var issueString = 'product=Headline&year=2012&month=12';
            $('.issues,#issuesBox').remove();
            var dWidth = $(window).width() * 0.9; 
            var dHeight = $(window).height() * 0.9;

            $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
                    height: dHeight,
                    width: dWidth,
                    modal: true,
                    draggable: false, 
                    resizable: false,
            });

            get_past_issues(issueString,2012,12,event.type);
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: If `$(window).scrollTop()` is zero, it's at the top, if it's the same as the `document.heigh - window.height` it's at the bottom.

Comment: @adeneo post this as answer!

Comment: There is an extra comma after `resizable: false`... Was that a copy paste mistake..?

Comment: @A.V that won't cause an issue

Answer (score 12, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="overflow: auto; height: 500px"></div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#mydiv").scroll(function()
    {
        var div = $(this);
        if (div[0].scrollHeight - div.scrollTop() == div.height())
        {
            alert("Reached the bottom!");
        }
        else if(div.scrollTop() == 0)
        {
            alert("Reached the top!");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

check

```
if($(window).scrollTop() == 0 || $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()- $(window).height()) {
   // do something
}
```