# jquery wait till scrolling is finished then execute function

Tags: jquery, onclick, jquery-animate

When i click the navigation button the page scrolls to top and then the menu should open.

At the moment i must click twice till it opens.

```
$("#nav-toggle").click(function() {
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
 this.classList.toggle( "active" );
  $("#menu").toggleClass("open");
});

$( window ).scroll(function() {
 $( "#nav-toggle" ).removeClass("active");
 $( "#menu" ).removeClass("open");
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0v2aahp/1/)

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. It checks if you're already at the top and if so, won't remove the classes you need to see the menu:

```
$("#nav-toggle").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
  $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
  $("#menu").toggleClass("open");
});

$( window ).scroll(function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() == 0 || $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height()- $(window).height()) {
   // do nothing
}
    else
  {
    // remove the classes
    $( "#nav-toggle" ).removeClass("active");
    $( "#menu" ).removeClass("open");
  }
});
```

Comment: Must give credit where it's due! The answer I found came from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193193/how-to-check-the-scroll-bar-status-is-already-at-top-or-at-end

Comment: i tried your solution but i still need to click twice till the menu opens

Comment: Glad you got it working! By the way which browser are you using for this? I confess I didn't check browser compatibility.

Comment: it's for my personal portfolio. It works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Which 98% of my visitors are using. So it works perfekt for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at below modified code:

https://jsfiddle.net/m0v2aahp/12/

```
  startScrollEvent();

$("#nav-toggle").click(function() {
  stopScrollEvent();
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "fast", function() {

    $("#menu").addClass("open");
    $("#nav-toggle").addClass("active");
    setTimeout(function() {
      startScrollEvent();
    }, 200);
  });
});

function startScrollEvent() {
  $(window).on("scroll.myscrollevent", function() {
    $("#nav-toggle").removeClass("active");
    $("#menu").removeClass("open");
  });
}

function stopScrollEvent() {
  $(window).off("scroll.myscrollevent");
}
```

Here we are starting and stopping the scroll event listener (which is actually removing the classes which are getting added in `animation`'s callback) to achieve our goal of adding the `active` and `open` class.

Answer (score 0):

the animation has a complete method.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

watch the example:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    width: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
    height: [ "toggle", "swing" ],
    opacity: "toggle"
  }, 5000, "linear", function() {
    $( this ).after( "<div>Animation complete.</div>" );
  });
});
```

Comment: already tried this but then the menu doesn't open at all, just the nav symbol disappears for a short time