# Functions working .click but not .scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a website using one html file and manipulating the contents with javascript. So certain actions trigger the next page to form. In this case I currently have a button on the bottom of each "page" which links to the next one I am trying to now integrate these same functions in a switch statement which works on scroll. However I cannot get this to work. I am also trying to put in an else if statement that is scroll is less then 0 the jquery loads the previous window.

```
var currentView = 'pageOne';
var display = $('.pageOne').css('display');
if (display == 'block') {
   changePageOne();
}
var display2 = $('.pageTwo').css('display');
if (display2 == 'block') {
   changePageTwo();
}
    $(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
      switch(currentView){
         case 'pageOne':
         changePageOne();
         break;
         case "pageTwo":
         changePageTwo();
         break;
         case "pageThree":
         changePageThree();
      }
     }
});


function changePageOne(){
           $('.fadeInRight').toggleClass("fadeOutLeft").toggleClass("fadeInRight");
           $('.fadeInLeft').toggleClass("fadeOutRight").toggleClass("fadeInLeft");
           $('.fadeInUp').toggleClass("fadeOutDown").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
           $('.fadeInDown').toggleClass("fadeOutUp").toggleClass("fadeInDown");
           setTimeout(function() {
           $('.slideOutRight').toggleClass("slideInLeft").toggleClass("slideOutRight");
           $('.slideOutLeft').toggleClass("slideInRight").toggleClass("slideOutLeft");
           $('.slideOutUp').toggleClass("slideInDown").toggleClass("slideOutUp");
           $('.slideOutDown').toggleClass("slideInUp").toggleClass("slideOutDown");
           $('.pageTwo').css("display", "block");
           }, 300);
           setTimeout(function() {
               $('.pageOne').css("display", "none");
           }, 300);
           currentView = "pageOne";
};

 function changePageTwo(){
           $('.slideInRight').toggleClass("slideOutRight").toggleClass('slideInRight');
           $('.slideInLeft').toggleClass("slideOutLeft").toggleClass('slideInLeft');
           $('.slideInUp').toggleClass("slideOutDown").toggleClass('slideInUp');
           $('.slideInDown').toggleClass("slideOutUp").toggleClass('slideInDown');
           $('.fadeOutRight').toggleClass("fadeInRight").toggleClass('fadeOutRight');
           $('.fadeOutLeft').toggleClass("fadeInLeft").toggleClass('fadeOutLeft');
           $('.fadeOutDown').toggleClass("fadeInDown").toggleClass('fadeOutDown');
           $('.fadeOutUp').toggleClass("fadeInUp").toggleClass('fadeOutUp');
           $('.pageThree').css("display", "block");
           setTimeout(function() {
               $('.pageTwo').css("display", "none");
            }, 300);
           currentView = "pageTwo";
};

 function changePageThree(){
           $('.fadeInRight').toggleClass("fadeOutLeft").toggleClass("fadeInRight");
           $('.fadeInLeft').toggleClass("fadeOutRight").toggleClass("fadeInLeft");
           $('.fadeInUp').toggleClass("fadeOutDown").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
           $('.fadeInDown').toggleClass("fadeOutUp").toggleClass("fadeInDown");
           setTimeout(function() {
           $('.slideOutRight').toggleClass("slideInLeft").toggleClass("slideOutRight");
           $('.slideOutLeft').toggleClass("slideInRight").toggleClass("slideOutLeft");
           $('.slideOutUp').toggleClass("slideInDown").toggleClass("slideOutUp");
           $('.slideOutDown').toggleClass("slideInUp").toggleClass("slideOutDown");
           $('.pageThree').css("display", "block");
           }, 300);
           setTimeout(function() {
               $('.pageTwo').css("display", "none");
           }, 300);
           currentView = "pageThree";
};
```

Comment: I think there is some typo error there in switch block. For `case: "pageFour"` body is missing.

Comment: Thanks yea I did make an error there.. I have a transition from page one - two. But the others do not happen?

Comment: Inside your `changePageOne()` method, you are transiting from `pageOne` to `pageTwo`, than `currentView` should contain `pageTwo` and not `pageOne`. Same thing applies to every other page transition.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri how do i change this so current view changes?

Comment: As I said, try changing the value of `currentView` in each `change...()` function. For example, in `changePageOne()` `currentView` should be `pageTwo`, in `changePageTwo()` `currentView` should be `pageThree` and so on. Actually your requirement is not so clear to answer me to the point.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri sorry I am struggling to understand what you mean could you please write me an example?

Comment: `function changePageOne(){ ..... currentView="pageTwo; }"` As you can see here in `changePageOne()` function, I have changed last line `currentView="pageOne"` to `currentView="pageTwo"`. Like this you have edit the last line in every function to update the `currentView` variable.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, thanks for the help. When I try this. on the down scroll all of the windows now disapear.

Comment: What actually you want to do? Please make your requirement clear so that I can answer to the point.

Comment: Okay. I have uploaded the website to AWS. here it is: http://maverickrevolution.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri above i added a link to the website. on click of the arrows at the bottom of the page. The window changes. I am trying to do the same thing on scroll on the up and down scroll. As you can see it works on the first page, but dose not go back up. and the other pages the functions only work as click.

Comment: Okay. Got it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193343/3709922 this might help you. It has similar case as yours.

Comment: The `if` condition within `$(window).scroll` is false. You have to make some changes there, which you do with the help of link which I just provided in  above comment.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, however this can help me do the scroll up and down, this dosent help me understand why the scroll down effect only works on the first page.

Comment: The effect works on only first page, because initially when you are on first page, you call the method `changePageOne()` to transition from `pageOne` to `pageTwo`, but in `changePageOne()` method, you have used `currentView="pageOne"` so your `currentView` is never changing and it is always staying at `pageOne`, and so you end up in calling `changePageOne()` method every time.

Comment: Methods other than `changePageOne()` are never getting called, so you are not able to make transitions further.

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri, I understand this now. It has begin to make sense. Is there a way if I changed the words ('two,three,one") too numbers that I could +1 to the end of the string every scroll?

Comment: @JigneshM.Khatri check comment under your answer please

Answer (score 0):

I have provided below methods with some changes made in your code. Using https://stackoverflow.com/a/14193343/3709922 this answer, you can track scroll events and using below methods, you can change pages. Hope it helps.

```
function changePageOne(){
       $('.fadeInRight').toggleClass("fadeOutLeft").toggleClass("fadeInRight");
       $('.fadeInLeft').toggleClass("fadeOutRight").toggleClass("fadeInLeft");
       $('.fadeInUp').toggleClass("fadeOutDown").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
       $('.fadeInDown').toggleClass("fadeOutUp").toggleClass("fadeInDown");
       setTimeout(function() {
       $('.slideOutRight').toggleClass("slideInLeft").toggleClass("slideOutRight");
       $('.slideOutLeft').toggleClass("slideInRight").toggleClass("slideOutLeft");
       $('.slideOutUp').toggleClass("slideInDown").toggleClass("slideOutUp");
       $('.slideOutDown').toggleClass("slideInUp").toggleClass("slideOutDown");
       $('.pageTwo').css("display", "block");
       }, 300);
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('.pageOne').css("display", "none");
       }, 300);
       currentView = "pageTwo"; // changed to pageTwo
}

function changePageTwo(){
       $('.slideInRight').toggleClass("slideOutRight").toggleClass('slideInRight');
       $('.slideInLeft').toggleClass("slideOutLeft").toggleClass('slideInLeft');
       $('.slideInUp').toggleClass("slideOutDown").toggleClass('slideInUp');
       $('.slideInDown').toggleClass("slideOutUp").toggleClass('slideInDown');
       $('.fadeOutRight').toggleClass("fadeInRight").toggleClass('fadeOutRight');
       $('.fadeOutLeft').toggleClass("fadeInLeft").toggleClass('fadeOutLeft');
       $('.fadeOutDown').toggleClass("fadeInDown").toggleClass('fadeOutDown');
       $('.fadeOutUp').toggleClass("fadeInUp").toggleClass('fadeOutUp');
       $('.pageThree').css("display", "block");
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('.pageTwo').css("display", "none");
        }, 300);
       currentView = "pageThree"; // changed to pageThree
}

function changePageThree(){
       $('.fadeInRight').toggleClass("fadeOutLeft").toggleClass("fadeInRight");
       $('.fadeInLeft').toggleClass("fadeOutRight").toggleClass("fadeInLeft");
       $('.fadeInUp').toggleClass("fadeOutDown").toggleClass("fadeInUp");
       $('.fadeInDown').toggleClass("fadeOutUp").toggleClass("fadeInDown");
       setTimeout(function() {
       $('.slideOutRight').toggleClass("slideInLeft").toggleClass("slideOutRight");
       $('.slideOutLeft').toggleClass("slideInRight").toggleClass("slideOutLeft");
       $('.slideOutUp').toggleClass("slideInDown").toggleClass("slideOutUp");
       $('.slideOutDown').toggleClass("slideInUp").toggleClass("slideOutDown");
       $('.pageFour').css("display", "block");
       }, 300);
       setTimeout(function() {
           $('.pageThree').css("display", "none");
       }, 300);
       currentView = "pageFour"; // changed to pageFour
}
```

**Edit:**
The above methods will only help to transition in forward order, i.e. from one to two and from two to three and so on. For backward transition, you have to create another methods same as these methods, but just changing the `currentView` order, and

`$('.pageTwo').css("display", "block");`

`setTimeout(function() {
     $('.pageOne').css("display", "none");
  }, 300);`

these lines to move in reverse (backward) order and check the scroll condition if user is scrolling backward or forward to make transition to backward of forward respectively.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but i have added this js to my file and on scroll it passes through all of the functions. I have uploaded my files to the same url as before so you can see what I mean. Thanks